# Display snmp traps in PHP

Tags: php, windows, snmp

How can I display snmp traps received on a PHP (5.4.5) server running on Windows ?
(SNMP::get of SNMP Class is only for SNMP object I think...)
Do I have to use socket_create ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Traps are sent spontaneously from snmp Agent hosts, so if you need to listen for them, you should probably open a UDP socket. This is in contrast to "get" and "set" messages, which are sent by Manager hosts, to request information from the Agent. I'm no php programmer, and I understand that the language can be used for other things than Web applications, but I still find the choice of language very unusual if you're writing a network management application.

Comment: Ok, il will try to open UDP socket (it s not for a network management application) il there is no better solution

Comment: One could argue that whatever receives a trap, is by definition a network management application. I shouldn't split hairs, though. =)

Comment: This one may be right but it s not really my debate =)

Comment: Hehe. Now, your problem will be what to do with the raw UDP datagram. You'll need something to decode the BER data.